# Timber: How to query posts of a single custom post type in archive.php

Tags: wordpress-theming, timber

I'm using Timber for Wordpress and when I use a custom query in archive.php to get posts of a custom post type, it returns posts of multiple post types.

I tried the exact same query in page.php and it worked perfectly.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
global $paged;
    if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
        $paged = 1;
    }
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'horse',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$context['horses'] = new Timber\PostQuery( $args );
```

I would expect that to return all items of post type 'horse', but other post types are also mixed in.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

---

I'm not sure if this is related, but I also added this to functions.php, inside the StarterSite class, in order to add my custom post type to the archive page:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

        // Get all your post types
        $post_types = get_post_types();

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
        return $query;
    }
 }
```

And this was added to the existing function named `__construct`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'namespace_add_custom_types') );
```

Comment: From looking at the code, I can’t find anything that might be off. Can you make sure that it’s not another plugin that interferes with the query? You could try to deactivate all plugins and check if the error still happens.

Comment: Sadly that didn't help. I was able to do what I want by creating a custom page template though, instead of relying on archive.php. The logic there is simpler so I must have added something to archive.php that was messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling it in the twig file?

```
{% for post in horses %}
{{ post.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, are you sure the post type name is horse and not horses?  If the wrong post type name is included in 'post_type' it would show all post types.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm calling it like you said, except with "horse" instead of "post".
I double checked the post type name and it's correct. If I use "horses" it doesn't show anything.
The only way I could get it to work was to create a category called "horse", add every horse post type to that category, then use `'category_name' => 'horse'` in the query args. This seems redundant though. I don't want to use a category when I should be able to use post type.

I used Pods Admin to create the horse post type, maybe one of the settings is wrong?

Comment: Since you're using the name `horses` within context, you would call it in the twig file as `{% for [any name here] in horses %}` and then `{{ [any-name-here].name }}`.  Try instead of name `{{ post.title }}`.  see if that works.

Comment: I was using `{% for horse in horses %}`. Tried `{% for post in horses %}` and didn't have any luck with that either. However I was able to do what I needed by adding the query to a custom page template instead of using archive.php. Not sure why it works one way and not the other, but the logic is simpler in the custom page template so I must have added something to archive.php that was messing it up. Thanks for your help.